# How to send form values of child components to parent which is implemented using value accessor?

Tags: angular

What is the best approach to get the values of a child component control group from parent component? I have implemented this using value accessor but i want to know what is the best approach. Here are the plunker demo i have created http://plnkr.co/edit/6sIKwAyF7KwsJbmk5KIJ?p=preview 
I have two issues:
1.If i have 10 inputs in child component should i write onchange() event for all the components? is there any way to avoid that?
2.In my child form both the fields are required.The parent form should be set invalid until all the controls of child form are valid which is not happening in my case.How can i do that?I am getting the values but Somebody please have a look at them and tell which one is the correct way of implementation and how can i avoid the above issues

```
<address [ngFormControl]="myForm.controls['Address']"></address>
```

This my address selector tag in parent component and

```
  constructor(@Optional() ngControl: NgControl, elementRef: ElementRef,fb: FormBuilder) {  
ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
this.onChange = (_) => {};
this.onTouched = (_) => {};
this.ngControl = ngControl;
    this.addressForm = fb.group({  
  'Address1':  ['',Validators.required],
  'City':['',Validators.required]
}); 
}
```

And this how i am assigning value to child component and building control group

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use 2 way binding.

When you bind each input, bind it with [(ngModel)].

Also, in your child component, use @Input for the address input and when you bind this, also use 2 way binding. In my example, I do not use ngFormControl, but I directly use @Input for my input and then do 2 way binding. I hope that will work for your case. Here is my code:

app.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import { Address } from 'src/address'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"  
        class="ui form">

    <div>  
      <label>Name:</label>  
      <input type="text" >  
    </div>
     <div>  
      <label>Phone:</label>  
      <input type="text"  >   
    </div>
    <address [(address)]="value.address"></address>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>  
  </form>  
  `,
  directives: [Address]
})
export class App {
  address: any;
  value: any; 

  constructor() {

    this.value = {
      address: {};
    }
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('you submitted value: ', this.value);  
  }
}
```

address.ts

```
import { Component, Input, Optional, ElementRef,EventEmitter,Renderer } from 'angular2/core';  
import {  FORM_DIRECTIVES,FormBuilder,ControlGroup,Validators,DefaultValueAccessor,NgControl,ControlValueAccessor} from 'angular2/common';


@Component({  
  selector: 'address',  
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],  
  template: `     <h2>Address:</h2>
     <div>  
      <label>Address:</label>  
      <input type="text"  [(ngModel)] = 'address.address'>
    </div>
     <div>   
      <label>City:</label>  
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)] = 'address.city' >
    </div>`,
  providers: [DefaultValueAccessor],
  inputs: ['address']
})
export class Address implements ControlValueAccessor{
  @Input address;
  constructor() {  

  }
}
```

Here is a pnkr example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/xeOKY8blBsFjzmb12El9